# java matlab how can I run a jar inside a matlab script?

Tags: java, matlab, jar

I created a jar that basically parses a bunch of pdf/text files and creates a .mat file. I also have a matlab script that loads that .mat file and compares the data against some other data. I want to ensure that the jar runs and updates the .mat file first. I want the first line of my matlab script to execute the jar and wait for it to complete. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to run by using system('java -jar jarname.jar')

Comment: why was this downvoted? it solved the problem stated in the question

Comment: because it's not really running java from matlab.  Matlab doesn't know that what it executing is java, it is simply making a system call. IMO

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the jar is in your Matlab class path. Presumably there is some static method you use in the jar, so from matlab your script can just call `com.mydomain.packagename.MainClass.main()`. Control doesn't return to Matlab until that call is finished, and, presumably, the .mat file is created. So your next matlab line would be `load('myfile.mat')`. If this isn't working, can you be more specific?

Comment: I use javaaddpath to add it to the dynamic path. I also add it through File->Set Path. When I tried to overwrite the jar file it said that I can't because matlab has it open so matlab is aware of it. However, I have no idea how to get it run. Just to be clear this is an executable jar(ie I can double click it and make it run) I basically just want to have matlab do the double clicking.  My package is called statementreader, the jar is called StatementReader. I have a Main class with the private static void main as the main class. No matter what I put, I get undefined variable.

Comment: I would expect `statementreader.Main.main()` to work. Can you be more specific about undefined variable?

Comment: it says "??? Undefined variable "statementreader" or class "statementreader.Main.main"." It's as if i just typed some random variable, but I got it to run using the system command

Answer (score 0):

Your Java api call must be blocking. Do not `return` from your Java parsing task until it is finished.