# Java class running with MATLAB software

Tags: java, matlab

I am going to run some Java files ending with `.class` and `.jar`.  How could I run these files inside of MATLAB?

Comment: Try this: [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325172/java-matlab-how-can-i-run-a-jar-inside-a-matlab-script)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The article [Bringing Java Classes into MATLAB Workspace](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/bringing-java-classes-and-methods-into-matlab-workspace.html) should be referenced for a thorough explanation of MATLAB's dynamic Java class path and how to add third-party and user-defined classes, but here are the Cliff's Notes:

Use [`javaaddpath`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/javaaddpath.html) to add Java archives (JAR files) or folders containing Java classes:

```
javaaddpath('C:\Folder\with\class\files\')
javaaddpath('C:\Path\to\jarfile.jar')
```

Then use `javaclasspath('-dynamic')` to see the dynamic class path, which should now reflect your additions.

To add to the static path, you'll need to edit javaclasspath.txt.

The [`import`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/import.html) command can then be used to [add classes or full packages](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/importing-classes.html) to the import list.